# Naming convention for methods whether they change an object or return changed object

Tags: python, methods

As it is said in the headline, is there that kind of naming convention, especially in python?

For example there are functions in python `sorted` (function that returns changed object, but doesn't change object) and `list` or `numpy.ndarray` method `sort` (returns nothing, but changes the object).

But for `reversed` and `list.reverse` functions it's not quite the case, `reversed` returns iterator.

In my case I have Permutation class and I want to add `inverse` functions for these two cases. Should I name them `inverted` and `inverse` (last one will be out of class) or like `get_inv` and `set_inv` respectively, because these methods are just like getters and setters (which is also quite true for `sorted` and `sort`)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is my convention which has served me well in all programming languages I have used:

1. A function with **no side-effects** which returns a **truth value** should be named after the property it queries and use an **adjective** as the last word, e.g. *sorted* or *items_sorted*.
2. A function with **no side-effects** which returns a **non-truth value** should be named after the result it returns and use a **noun** as the last word, e.g. *sorted_items*.
3. A function **with side-effects** should be named after what it does and use a **verb** as the first word, e.g. *sort* or *sort_items*.

Rule 1 and 2 is also applicable to variable names.

In your concrete example i would use the identifier *invert* for the method which inverts a permutation, and *inverse* for a method which returns the inverse of a permutation.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the answer!
I suppose you mean by side-effects - changes that happen to existing objects, right?
But what does mean truth and non-truth values? Boolean and non-boolean?

Comment: @DamirAktemov Yes, a truth value is the same as a boolean.

Comment: @DamirAktemov Av side-effect means that the state of the running program is altered, i.e. a variable is changed or input or output is read or written.

Comment: @DamirAktemov I think August means "side effect" in a [functionnal programming](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Functional_programming) sense, which is opposed to "pure".